# Multisite are not creating folders for the subsites

Tags: multisite

Sorry, tried looking around for an answer for this but couldn't find any existing threads. I set up multisite locally, I'm using Xampp, and for some odd reason there are no directories being created by the subsites. I can see the sites being created in the network admin but can't access the dashboard because the subdirectory doesn't exist, error 403. It's setup to use subdirectories, not subdomains. I'm not sure if this helps but this is what I got from the apache error log. Keep in mind that there's no invalid character on the site names, no special characters or even spaces just alpha chars.

```
[Fri May 13 01:01:58.614772 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1716] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:65164] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/network/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file
[Fri May 13 01:27:40.071626 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1704] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:49674] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/test1/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/sites.php
[Fri May 13 01:27:47.716878 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1740] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:49675] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/test1/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file
[Fri May 13 01:28:21.030191 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1728] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:49714] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/test1/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/sites.php
[Fri May 13 01:41:40.543810 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1740] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50319] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/test2/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/sites.php
[Fri May 13 01:55:10.722134 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1704] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50884] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/site1/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/sites.php
[Fri May 13 02:13:51.948250 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1716] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:51712] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/check/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/site-new.php?id=6
[Fri May 13 02:23:58.439305 2016] [core:error] [pid 70836:tid 1716] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:52103] AH00127: Cannot map GET /multisite/wordpress/test3/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/multisite/wordpress/wp-admin/network/site-new.php?id=7
```

Thanks!

### `.htaccess` file (from pastebin in comments)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /multisite/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) A:/MyProjects/JunRoot/Multisite/wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ A:/MyProjects/JunRoot/Multisite/wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: There is not physical sub directly created in a multi site network! Confirm that `.htaccess` is writable and you paste the correct rules.

Comment: Ugh.. really? I did paste the correct rule. Any way to confirm the sites are created in the DB then? How do I reply with the code, it says too long

Comment: Here's the rule

http://pastebin.com/2m0Rf1Ee

is that right? @Sumit

Comment: @HinampsPaksh : Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/227270/edit) with any relevant updates, rather than trying to add them as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the various recommended `.htaccess` configurations on the [Codex's `.htaccess`](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) page. Here's the one for subdirectory Multisite later than WordPress 3.5:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
>
> # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
> RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
> RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
> RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
> RewriteRule . index.php [L]
> ```

I note that in your `.htaccess` file, you're trying to `Rewrite` things to a file location (`A:/...`) rather than to a URL. I think this is probably the error you're running into.

Comment: Worked! I rewrote the location to a URL instead of the path to the directory and it worked. Thanks! 

I'll remember to edit my posts on future questions. Sorry about that!

PS: I can't upvote your answer. Seems that my account is too new!

Comment: Even if you can't upvote answers, @HinampsPaksh, you should still be able to **Accept** this answer as correct (if it solved your problem). Doing that may help others find a solution to their question.